# @font-type doesn't load on mobile and IE (wordpress despite correct CSS)

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face

Hi guys I've done a fair amount of digging and this persistent problem is driving me insane.

I can't get my font-type to load for mobile and IE. 
My site is http://kays.vurb.us/

I am talking about the hamburger icon when in responsive mode. It uses the letter 'a' with a special font 'etmodules'.

This is how my css looks like:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'etmodules';
src: url('etmodules_v2_4.eot');
src: url('etmodules_v2_4.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('etmodules_v2_4.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('etmodules_v2_4.woff') format('woff'),
     url('etmodules_v2_4.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('etmodules_v2_4.svg#etmodules_v2_4regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

I put the files in my main wordpress directory. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Since it doesn't work on IE and mobile I tried looking at the IE developer tools but I can't figure out why the font won'
t download or load on the site. Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder called fonts or any name you want inside your theme folder, then upload your font files inside that folder

Then use absolute path e.g

```
 src: url(http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/fonts/Arvo-Regular.ttf);
```